# What is the underscore function for?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've been using underscore as a collection of statics.

What is the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) function for:

```
var _ = function(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
  };
```

What is an example of how you would use this?

Comment: Really intelligent question, seriously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also can use Underscore as a wrapper function, to get a more [OOP-like style](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-138):

```
_(val).method(…);
// instead of the equal
_.method(val, …);
```

These wrapper objects also allow [chaining](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-138):

```
_.chain(val).method1(…).method2(…);
// or
_(val).chain().method1(…).method2(…);
```

Answer (score 4):

You wrap objects with it:

```
_([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

And then use Underscore functions on the wrapped object:

```
_([1, 2, 3, 4]).shuffle()
```

Comment: It's just a variable name - they could have called it `a`, but `_` obviously works with the script already being called *underscore*

Comment: The _ function doesn't actually allow chaining underscore functions - the example above only works because 'map' and 'filter' are built-in array functions. They won't use underscore's implementation, so you could run into compatibility issues with e.g. IE 8. Use the _.chain function for chaining.