# How does the _() function (object wrapper) in Underscore.js work?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am working on underscore.js and I got stuck in the very first function.

```
// Create a safe reference to the Underscore object for use below.
var _ = function(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
  };

// Test Examples
var obj = {
    name : 'Francis',
    gender: 'male'
}
var test = _(obj);
console.log(test); // _ {_wrapped: Object}
                   // Why statement this._wrapped = obj; still got executed?

var Man = function() {
    this.age = 30;
    this.people = "John";
    return this;
    this.man = "me";
}
var me = new Man();
console.log(me) // Man {age: 30, people: "John"}
                // There is no "man" property because function Man returns
                // before executing to the last statement.
```

I am trying to figure out what `_` (underscore) does in here: I think it serves as a constructor and returns an instance with all the functions defined in underscore.js. So it'll be more convenient to invoke the functions with simple syntax.

Fox example:

```
var anotherList = [1, 2];
_.each(anotherList, alert); // alert "1", "2"

var anotherObj = {"name": "H"};
var anotherObj = _(anotherObj);
anotherObj.each(alert); // alert "H"
```

But what's the mechanism behind all this?

How `this._wrapped = obj;` works?

Comment: The body of your question is entirely different from the title. Which question do you want answered? Oh, `_` is just a valid name for an identifier.

Comment: Actually it's sort of like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378628/what-is-the-underscore-function-for . But after reading a lot of related questions, I still can't figure out how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_` function is recursive. You call it, then it calls itself a second time. Let's take a look.

```
var _ = function(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
  };
```

When you do `_(obj)` with `obj={...}`, your object fulfills the second `if` condition -- `this` is not an instance of `_`, as it was not called as a constructor (`this` is the global object). Then, it returns `new _(obj)`, calling `_` as a constructor. This second time around, `this` is indeed an instance of `_`, so neither condition is fulfilled. Now, it reaches the final line. Being a constructor, it implicitly returns `this` to the first time you called it.

You now have a `_` object.

Comment: It explains a lot! But how does `test.each(alert)` work? In underscore.js source code, `_.each(obj, iteratee, [context])` takes at least two arguments, while here we just pass one `iteratee` argument to it and it works anyway.

Comment: Because you have a wrapped underscore object, which gets all those properties set on it.

Answer (score 6):

The function at the top acts "sort of like" a constructor for something that is "sort of like" a class in JavaScript (a very loose description: search `prototype`, `class` and `javascript` for more accuracy).

In this case, the "class" has one member (`._wrapped`) which is set to the object specified (`obj`).  (Elsewhere, in `underscore.js`, all the functions of the "class" will be added using `.prototype`).

The two tests at the beginning are to prevent incorrect use:

```
if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
```

checks that you are not passing an instance of the `_` class into the constructor (if you do, it just returns that instance).  This will stop:

```
var a = {...};
var b = new _(a);
var c = new _(b);
```

creating a doubly-wrapped object (`c` will be the same as `b`).

The second test:

```
if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
```

checks that you've correctly used `new` when creating an instance (or, conversely, allows you not to have to remember to use `new` all the time).

When called as in your code:

```
var test = _(obj);
```

the value of `this` inside the function that is `_` will be the global scope, and hence not an instance of the `_` class.  In this case, it will use `new` for you to create a new instance of the `_` class and return it.  (If it didn't do this, and you didn't use `new`, then you wouldn't get a new object and would end up polluting the global object).

If it is called as in my example above (using `new`), then `this` inside the function will be the newly-created `_` object.  This *will* be an `instanceof _` and so will proceed to the main part of the constructor:

```
this._wrapped = obj;
```

which saves a copy of the object being wrapped in the new instance.  Thus:

```
var a = {...};
var b = _(a);
var c = new _(a);
```

will create both `b` and `c` as new instances of the `_` class.  Whether you *should* use the `new`, or rely on constructors to do it for you is a question for another time.